# Passenger Error: Detaching it from the pool

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm getting this error on `passenger 4.0.37-2` and `ruby 2.2.2p95`

```
[ 2015-05-20 22:43:04.0051 23732/7f776aaa9700 Pool2/Pool.h:777 ]: Process (pid=24139, group=/home/ubuntu/foco-virtual/src/hivexp#default) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.

App 24149 stdout:
App 23819 stderr: 

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:356:in `trap'

App 23819 stderr: :
App 23819 stderr: Invalid argument - SIGKILL
App 23819 stderr:  (
App 23819 stderr: Errno::EINVAL
App 23819 stderr: )
```

Comment: I believe Ruby 2.2 support was added in Passenger 4.0.55.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue which has been fixed in a Passenger release half a year ago. Try upgrading to the latest Passenger version.